# Прибавление времени к уже заданному

Tags: python, django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение. 
Только начинаю изучать Python и Django.
Задача в следующем: хочу сделать автоматический просчет времени исполнения заказа.
К примеру, разместил заказ, указал, что будет готов через 10 часов, через форму размещения заказа. Пошел обратный отсчет, который желательно выводить в вэб-морду. 
Но может произойти так, что во время исполнения одного заказа поступил следующий, и при его добавлении нужно, чтобы время его исполнения плюсовалось к предыдущему времени + тех. перерыв, час, например.

Как это можно реализовать? Прошу прощения за сумбур.

Сейчас начал составлять поля для таблицы в models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class TimerOrder(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "orderdb"
    order_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    order_id = models.IntegerField
    order_time = models.DateTimeField
    order_completetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order_postprocessing = models.TimeField
```

**Обновление**

Код поправил. Данные успешно заносятся в sql через админку. Подскажите, как быть дальше:

```
from django.db import models

from datetime import timedelta

import datetime

import time

class TimerOrder(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "order"

    order_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    order_Print_start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    order_Print_end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    order_Print_postprocessing_time = models.TimeField()
    order_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order_comments = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласно твоей задаче, необходимо реализовать очередь заказов, т.е. "очередь".
Для этого можно создать отдельную модель. 
Добавлять в очередь по одному заказу, а если время его прошло, то удалять (эту логику вынести, естественно, за модель).
Реализовать можно по-разному очередь, решать тебе.
Надеюсь, натолкнул на полезную мысль.